# Convert a 360 degree video to a single image

Tags: 360-panorama

I recently took a few 10 second video clips of my surroundings, by simply taking starting a video, rotating around, staying in the same spot, and ending the video when I reached the point where I started.  Now I have a lot of 10 second video clips, and I was wondering if there was a way or a software out there to convert these videos, into one very wide, still image.

I also got thinking, and was wondering if there was some way to make my own program to construct a single image out of the video, any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed write your own program (in some extend) to do this *stitching* operation. You should use opencv to do this and program your project in python or c++, depending on your preferences.

Here some pointers to start:

[opencv: tutorial stitcher](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html)

[stitching from several cameras in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348674/how-can-i-stitch-images-from-video-cameras-in-real-time)

[video stitching](http://answers.opencv.org/question/100189/real-time-video-stitching-from-initial-stitching-computation/)

As a bonus, your can think of doing *superresolution* process to increase the level of details of the resulting image !

[Robust And Fast Super Resolution](http://www1.idc.ac.il/toky/videoProc-07/projects/SuperRes/srproject.html)

[opencv: superresolution](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/superres/doc/super_resolution.html)

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, and I will try to make my own program.  But since I do not have much experience programming in c++ or python (mostly just java), I was wondering if there is some software out on GitHub or someplace else on the internet which I could use?

Comment: If you are fluent in Java, c++ and python will be easy. Some tutorials or examples are an easy first step IMO. There are no ready to use softs.

Answer (score 0):

This command extracts one frame from time 00:00:02 of the input video and saves it into image.jpg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:02 -vframes 1 image.jpg
```

Or you can use Virtual Dub: reduce the number of frames per seconds in video/options, then save as "image sequence".

Then you will need a "panorama stitcher" like Hugin to properly stitch together all the extracted frames into one single image without overlappings or discontinuities.